# ELSE statement is getting skipped

Tags: python, django

In my template, I am trying check if a list is not empty.  If it is not empty, I check for something.  However, if the list is empty, it 'else' is never evaluated.

```
    {% for secret in secrets %}
      <div class="secrets">
        <p>{{secret.secret}}</p>
        {%load humanize%}
        <p>({{secret.created_at|naturaltime}})</p>
        <p>{{secret.likes.all|length}} likes</p>
        {% for like in secret.likes.all %}
          {% if like %}
            {% if like.id == request.session.user_id %}
              <p>You liked this</p>
            {% else %}
              <a href="{% url 'secrets:like_it' id=secret.id %}">Like</a>
            {% endif %}
          {% else %} <!--This seems to get skipped-->
            <a href="{% url 'secrets:like_it' id=secret.id %}">Like</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: @abccd This is Django's templating language, in which **Python** is in fact an appropriate tag of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if/else` is within the for loop.  If the sequence being iterated over (`secret.likes.all`) is empty, that `if/else` statement will never be executed.  For an action to occur when there was no iteration, use something like the following:

```
{% for like in secret.likes.all %}
  {% if like %}
    {% if like.id == request.session.user_id %}
      <p>You liked this</p>
    {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'secrets:like_it' id=secret.id %}">Like</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% else %} <!--This seems to get skipped-->
  <a href="{% url 'secrets:like_it' id=secret.id %}">Like</a>
{% endfor %}
```